# How to make a woocommerce order notes in checkout to be a datepicker

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I am trying to customize a woocommerce checkout page, I need to change an order notes box in checkout page from textbox to datepicker, I need a help on it

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make the order notes a datepicker? That's a text area. It would be wrong to mess up the existing input field type & change it to a datepicker.

Instead it would be better to add a datepicker field separately either via a code snippet or via a plugin. Below code can help you add a datepicker on the WooCommerce checkout page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'display_extra_fields_after_billing_address' , 10, 1 );
function display_extra_fields_after_billing_address () {
    _e( "Delivery Date: ", "add_extra_fields");
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="add_delivery_date" class="add_delivery_date" placeholder="Delivery Date">
  <?php 
}
```

The above code is taken from this article, which includes options to add the datepicker at other places on the checkout page: https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/

Also you can use this free plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/